# как прочитать значение value в input ( JQuery NO )

Tags: javascript, input, if, value

**HELLO**
Имеется несколько вариантов ответа , по нажатию на кнопку нужно проверить , если value== a , ответ правильный , если b , неверный ... И после проверки вывести фразу под кнопкой верно или нет ) помогите пожалуйста ... 
P.s : мои знания js оставляют желать лучшего

```js
function check(){


}
```

```html
<form class="inputs">
                <div id="inp1">    
                    <input type="radio" value="a" name="q1" > Pregunta1</input>
                  </div>
                <div id="inp2">
                    <input type="radio" value="b" name="q1" > Pregunta2</input>
                  </div>
                <div id="inp3">    
                    <input type="radio" value="b" name="q1" > Pregunta3</input>
                  </div>
                <div id="inp4">    
                    <input type="radio" value="b" name="q1"> Pregunta4</input>
                  </div>
            
            </form>
             <button id="buttonCheck" onclick="check()">CHECK</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {
  var selected = document.querySelector(".inputs input[name='q1']:checked");
  var value = selected ? selected.value : "NONE";
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  console.log(value);
  if (value == "a")
    status.textContent = "Right answer";
  else if (value == "b")
    status.textContent = "Wrong answer";
  else
    status.textContent = "Answer is not selected";
}
```

```html
<form class="inputs">
  <div id="inp1">
    <label><input type="radio" value="a" name="q1"/> Pregunta1</label>
  </div>
  <div id="inp2">
    <label><input type="radio" value="b" name="q1"/> Pregunta2</label>
  </div>
  <div id="inp3">
    <label><input type="radio" value="b" name="q1"/> Pregunta3</label>
  </div>
  <div id="inp4">
    <label><input type="radio" value="b" name="q1"/> Pregunta4</label>
  </div>
</form>
<br/>
<button id="buttonCheck" onclick="check()">CHECK</button>
<div id="status">...</div>
```